# CakePHP2系でretweet機能のロジックを知りたいです。

Tags: cakephp

現在、CakePHP2でTwitterのクローンサイトを作成してます。そこでRetweet機能を作成しているのですが、ロジックが分からず設計の段階でかなり時間を労してしまっています。
＜仕様＞
現状homeページに他ユーザーと自身の投稿が記事のタイトル/投稿内容/comment（コメント入力フォームに飛ぶリンク）の順で表示されています。そこで、さらにcomment（リンク）の横にretweetというリンクを配置して、クリックすると自分の今までの投稿が表示されるファイルにそのリツイートした投稿を表示できるようにしたいです。

テーブルはpostテーブル、userテーブルの二つで処理可能かと推測しているのですが、色々sqlなどのリレーションを考えていると頭が混乱しどう作成するべきか分からない状態です。
どなたかアドバイス頂けると幸いです。

Comment: 本家Twitterの設計、ロジックはテーブル定義も含めて外部から知る術はありません。 / あなたの考えるReTweet(のようなもの)の仕様を決めた上で、何に詰まっているのかをもう少し具体的に書くとアドバイスが付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 承知致しました！ありがとうございます。仕様を練って、再度投稿させて頂きます！